# How to subtract records in Oracle SQL without unique key

Tags: sql, oracle10g, subtraction, cumulative-sum

I have three tables `schedule_master`,`schedule_child` and `sent_schedule`.My table structure as below

```
create table schedule_master(
mp_order varchar2(20),
ent_date date,
ent_time date
);

create table schedule_child(
mp_order VARCHAR2(20),
party_name varchar2(30),
req_date date,
purchaser_name varchar2(25),
order_no varchar2(20),
item_size varchar2(30),
item_quality varchar2(100),
ply varchar2(30),
uom varchar2(10),
po_qty number,
po_rate FLOAT
);

CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE_SENT(
ENT_DATE DATE,
ENT_TIME DATE,
ORDER_NO NUMBER,
ITEM_SIZE VARCHAR2(150),
PO_QTY NUMBER,
SENT_QTY NUMBER
);
```

First two tables are data entry form and doing well and third one table is for issuing the material.When
i do enter my record in this table i want to get result by subtracting two records of other tables.I am using this statement for my result but this give me 
result with wrong subtraction.My code is below

```
SELECT SC.ORDER_NO,SC.ITEM_SIZE || ' ' || SC.UOM || ' ' || SC.PLY || ' < ' || SC.ITEM_QUALITY || ' > 
' as "ITEM SIZE",sc.po_qty,NVL(SS.SENT_QTY,0)SENT ,sc.po_qty-NVL(SS.SENT_QTY,0) AS "BALANCE" FROM 
schedule_child SC 
LEFT JOIN SCHEDULE_SENT SS ON sC.order_no=sS.order_no
WHERE sc.order_no=sc.order_no
ORDER BY sc.mp_order ASC;
```

Above code gives me wrong result and tried many time to solve this result is below

```
  po_order        item_size                              po_qty  sent  balance 
 21563  17.25X9.75X20 INCH 7 PLY CTN BROWN               127    0     127
 21563  17.25X10.75X20 INCH 7 PLY CTN BROWN              508    0     508
 21368  3.35X8.5 INCH 3 PLY STIFFNER BROWN               11643  180   11463
 21368  16.5X11.75X16.5 INCH 7 PLY CTN BROWN              95    180   -85
 21368  16.5X11.75X17.5 INCH 7 PLY CTN BROWN             182    180   2
 21534  34.75X4.5X34.75X34.75 CM 5 PLY STIFFNER WHITE    3060   0     3060
 21472  22.25X17X11 INCH 7 PLY CTN BROWN                 226    0     226
 21472  22.25X17X15 INCH 7 PLY CTN BROWN                 598    0     598
```

As we can see above result that is wrong.I just issued only `180 ctn`and should be balance only this item to `2` but this code is giving me also other items subtract as well.I want the result like below

```
po_order        item_size                              po_qty  sent  balance 
 21563  17.25X9.75X20 INCH 7 PLY CTN BROWN               127    0     127
 21563  17.25X10.75X20 INCH 7 PLY CTN BROWN              508    0     508
 21368  3.35X8.5 INCH 3 PLY STIFFNER BROWN               11643  0     11643
 21368  16.5X11.75X16.5 INCH 7 PLY CTN BROWN              95    0     95
 21368  16.5X11.75X17.5 INCH 7 PLY CTN BROWN             182    180   2
 21534  34.75X4.5X34.75X34.75 CM 5 PLY STIFFNER WHITE    3060   0     3060
 21472  22.25X17X11 INCH 7 PLY CTN BROWN                 226    0     226
 21472  22.25X17X15 INCH 7 PLY CTN BROWN                 598    0     598
```

Comment: Please provide sample data to reproduce the case.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING won't help you get answers any faster. It's also somewhat impolite to SHOUT at us when you're asking us for free help.